# Vault port forwarding with Vagrant on Macos

Tags: macos, vagrant, hashicorp-vault, forwarding, vault

I have a vagrant machine (almalinux/8) on my MacOS (Big Sur).

I have configured my Vagrantfile to forward Vautl port

```
    config.vm.define "vault" do |s|
      s.vm.hostname = "vault"
      s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.30.3.2"
      s.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8200, host: 8200, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
    end
```

After launching the machine, I start vault from command line.

```
$ vault server -dev
[vagrant@vault ~]$ sudo vault server -dev
==> Vault server configuration:

             Api Address: http://127.0.0.1:8200
                     Cgo: disabled
         Cluster Address: https://127.0.0.1:8201
              Go Version: go1.17.7
```

If I try to connect to vault server from the host (macos) I get this error.

```
% curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8200
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8200 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8200
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrog?